# Querying indirect relationships between objects

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Using Laravel 5.6, let's say I have the following database tables:

```
networks   users        vlans
--------   -----        -----
id         id           id
           network_id   network_id
           vlan_id
```

And these relations:

```
class Network extends Model {
    public function users() { return $this->hasMany("User"); }
    public function vlans() { return $this->hasMany("Vlan"); }
}

class User extends Model {
    public function network() { return $this->belongsTo("Network"); }
    public function vlan()    { return $this->belongsTo("Vlan"); }
}

class Vlan extends Model {
    public function network() { return $this->belongsTo("Network"); }
    public function user()    { return $this->hasOne("User"); }
}
```

My question is: given a `Network` ID, is there an easy way to determine which `Vlan` objects are **not** assigned to a `User`?

This is very early stages (and I'm quite new to Laravel) so if I've screwed up the relationships I have no qualms about starting over. I've considered changing things so that the `vlans` table has a `user_id` foreign key but that seems backwards. (And it would just leave me with the same question in reverse: how to find all the `User` objects that don't have a `Vlan` assignment!)

Comment: Is this a many to many relationship? As in, a vlan can belong to multiple user and an user can have multiple vlan?

Comment: You only have one vlan able to be assigned to a user..

Comment: @ChinLeung no, it's one-to-one; VLANs are exclusive to users, and users can only have one.

Comment: Have you seen this? It may be helpful: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a scope to your Vlan model:

```
public function scopeNotAssigned($query, $id)
{
    return $query->whereNotIn(
        'id',
        User::where('network_id', $id)->select('vlan_id')->get()->pluck('vlan_id')->toArray()
    );
}
```

Then suppose you have a network:

```
$network = \App\Network::first();
```

You can retrieve the non-assigned vlans in the network like this:

```
$vlans = \App\Vlan::notAssigned($network->id)->get();
```

---

Otherwise you can also add a relationship with the users in your Vlan model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User');
}
```

Then you could use the `whereDoesntHave` function:

```
$vlans = Vlan::whereDoesntHave('users', function ($query) use ($network) {
    return $query->where('network_id', $network->id);
})->get();
```